# How to make a responsive theme in Zen 5? Modules and procedures to keep or to leave from older Zen versions

Tags: blocks, panels, theming

I'm using [Zen theme](http://drupal.org/project/zen) back from 2007, when Drupal 5 comes out (anyone remembers those subtheme directories put into the main zen directory?). Thanks to this theme reliability and awesome community, the small team I work in completed several projects for customers in Drupal 5, 6 and 7. Since the theme base is standard, projects change hands smoothly and common solutions were standardized internally.

Now, customers start to get more demanding about mobile devices and building a separate theme or a simple alternate stylesheet for mobiles is not enough anymore. "Responsive" become a term used by the marketing people too. And here starts our problems as developers.

A video from [July 2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4xdymhPiVQ) by Palantir is a good starting point, and the [Responsive web design](http://drupal.org/node/1388492) handbook is extensive. Maybe, too extensive. The number of new concepts is overwhelming (to me).

Compass, SASS, the use of a Ruby CSS preprocessor (compass) running as a server to generate CSS files from SASS, and not to improve loading times by the client are some of the new *design* concepts implemented through Zen Grids. Respond.js and HTML5 shim seems to be new *retrocompatibility* concepts. Zen Grids [seems to be able to do](http://designshack.net/articles/css/zen-grids-a-responsive-grid-system-built-on-sass/) most of the work Panels and templates used to do.

Anyone here started from a previous Zen theme and set of tools like view blocks, Panels and Mini panels, field templates, conditional stylesheets and now have *successfully* changed the working method to adapt to Zen 5 new features? What should I keep and what should I have better to forget after entering in the Zen 5 world? Here some tools that seems to make obsolete some old companions:

- Field / view field templates > Fences?
- Panels > Zen grids?

How blocks and views will adapt in this new approach, looking for responsiveness? How navigation? I used awfully a lot Menu Block and now I see responsive menus [like this](http://media02.hongkiat.com/responsive-web-nav/demo/index.html) popping out. Conditional stylesheets are something [I can forget of](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/support/) because of Compass? How can I adapt user-loaded images through IMCE / TinyMCE?

I don't want to use old, unfit tools in a new environment, so what's the best, practical approach while selecting modules and designing the theme from a "old school" Zen enthusiast point of view *in your experience*? Priorities for my team is to keep low the number of contrib modules and identify a standard process to create quickly complex responsive layout for nodes and for views keeping code as clean and maintainable as possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: This question is too broad to really be able to answer, but have you seen [The Zen cheat sheet](http://www.palantir.net/sites/default/files/blog/misc/zen_reference.pdf)?

Comment: This is for Zen 2 / Drupal 6. I'm talking about Zen 5 / Drupal 7 . Valuable reference anyway! I used cheatsheet in the past almost for template suggestions.

Comment: I agree with @beth, this question is far too broad (and yet somehow too localised as well) and comes under the category of "shopping list question", so it will be closed. Fair warning though, I've opened a [meta discussion](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/what-do-we-want-to-do-with-un-constructive-questions-that-have-a-bounty-on-them) so the community can have some input on exactly how/when that happens. Please feel free to contribute to that discussion, nothing will happen here until a satisfactory consensus has been agreed

Comment: Yes, broad, but...

Comment: Perhaps the question is broad, but... the short answer is that converting from Zen 3 to Zen 5 is quite easy, even for an existing site. You don't really need to touch Zen Grids; just use Zen and Panels the way you are used to.  The new learning is mostly responsive images, and SASS/COMPASS, and that is valuable in itself. I wouldn't worry about replacing Panels with theme-based grids unless you have a specific use-case, because the Panels-Grids-Drupal8 world is still pretty unstable.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid getting confused.  Zen Grids is not the same as the panels module.  The fences module just makes it easier to override the default field html output.  The responsive menu you showed is just css and a media query.

A little zen might help also, take a deep breath and repeat after me, "It is all just css."